# Discord.py read messages from channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I m trying to listen to all messages from specific channels inside guilds that i m not owner, i started to trying listen to all messages with the code below, without success. How can i do that if possible using the channel id?

Thank you!

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
guild = discord.Guild
messages =  []


print("Bot started")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    msg = message.content

    if msg != "" :
 
        messages.append(msg)

    while True:
        print(messages)
    
client.run('TOKENHERE')
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=fetch%20channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_channel

Answer (score 1):

Every `message` object has the channel it was sent in as an attribute. You can simply compare the ids, and if they match, run your code.
Also be sure that you have the `messages` intent, in order for the `on_message()` event to work, like said [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message).

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
guild = discord.Guild
messages =  []


print("Bot started")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    channelIDsToListen = [ 12345, 54321 ] # put the channels that you want to listen to here

    if message.channel.id in channelIDsToListen:

        if message.content != "" :
 
            messages.append(message.content)

        print("New message: " + message.content)
    
client.run('TOKENHERE')
```

Comment: Does it works for channels i m not administrator????

Comment: I d like to listen channel that i m not the owner.

Is it possible?

Comment: As long as the bot is on said server and it has read-permissions in channels it should listen to, this solution will work.

Comment: Thanks for reply bro. As i could check here on StackOverflow "Bots cannot accept invites or join servers/guilds any other way than being manually invited. A user with manager server permissions must authorize the bot and the permissions said bot will be granted upon joining." Thats my case, i m on the server but my bot isnt. I dont have manager server permissions to authorize the bot joining. Can i do that with my profile that has read-permissions in channel? Is there any solution for it? If possible and you could update your answer it should be awesome.

Thank you bro, take care.

Comment: No that isn't possible.